# Deriving another type name literally from a given type name

Tags: c++, templates

Now I have this:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
class Something {
   ...
}
```

but since `U` is *always* `{PREPEND_NAME_}T` and `PREPEND_NAME_` is literal and will never change, I'd like to save this second type name, somehow building that type name using `T` and the prepend name. Is this possible? Of course the preprocessor will not work...

Comment: No, this is not possible. You could however have some type lookup (something like a type traits) like `typename Traits<T>::Foo` which is a typedef for `Foo_T`. Or `T` has a typedef for its corresponding type with the prepended stuff. Like `class A { typedef Foo Foo_A; };` Then you can use `typename T::Foo` in your template.

Comment: Or you have `#define SOMETHING(T) Something<T, PREPEND_NAME_ ## T>` but I wouldn't recommend it for *several* reasons.

Comment: @ leeme. Could you explain a little bit why you would not recommend  it ?

Comment: @Davidbrcz E.g. if T is a typedef or a subtype of something else, things will break. E.g.: Consider `class Widget` and `class Foo_Widget` which should be used as the type pair here. Then I have a `typedef Widget MyWidget` for some reason and want to be able to write `SOMETHING(MyWidget)` which becomes `Something<Foo_MyWidget, MyWidget>` which is illegal since I didn't also typedef the Foo version. And if the two classes where in some other class or namespace called `Outer`, we write `Something(Outer::Widget)` which will also be incorrect (`Foo_Outer::Widget` instead of `Outer::Foo_Widget`)